# Create new count columns based off the number of rows by a column

Tags: r

I have a very large data frame with other variables in it, but I would like to collapse this data frame by id and create new columns with the frequency counts of the obj code.

This is part of my dataframe.

```
id <- c("Adam", "Adam", "Adam", "Adam", "Adam", "Adam", "John", "John", "John", "Kim")
obj <- c("21", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "25", "27", "28", "28")
df <- data.frame(id, obj)
```

And this is my desired output:

```
id2 <- c("Adam", "John", "Kim")
obj.21 <- c(2,0,0)
obj.22 <- c(1,0,0)
obj.23 <- c(1,0,0)
obj.24 <- c(1,0,0)
obj.25 <- c(1,1,0)
obj.27 <- c(0,1,0)
obj.28 <- c(0,1,1)
output <- data.frame(id2, obj.21, obj.22,obj.23,obj.24,obj.25,obj.27,obj.28)
output
```

I want to count the number of times that obj code (obj) appears for each person (id).  Each obj code should have their own column with the counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(df, id ~ paste0("obj", obj), value.var = "obj", fun.aggregate = length)

    id obj21 obj22 obj23 obj24 obj25 obj27 obj28
1 Adam     2     1     1     1     1     0     0
2 John     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
3  Kim     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be `table`

```
table(df)
#      obj
#id     21 22 23 24 25 27 28
#  Adam  2  1  1  1  1  0  0
#  John  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
#  Kim   0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   count(id, obj) %>%
   mutate(obj = str_c("obj", obj)) %>%
   spread(obj, n, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 3 x 8
#  id    obj21 obj22 obj23 obj24 obj25 obj27 obj28
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Adam      2     1     1     1     1     0     0
#2 John      0     0     0     0     1     1     1
#3 Kim       0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```